# select from column if exist, if not value is NULL

Tags: c#, mysql, ddl

I have a windows forms application (C#) that reads some data from MySQL database. In a new version I needed to add a new column in one of the tables (to add some functionality). Sometimes I need to make a restore database (from dump file). If I restore the old table from the old database (without the new column) I get "unnknown column" error.

How should I alter my SQL command to select data from this table? If 'newcolumn' exists, I need to select data, if not I need to select NULL.

```
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(
        "SELECT my_id AS Id,myColumn1 AS Column1,myColumn2 AS Column2,
         newcolumn AS NewColumn (here IF NOT EXIST = NULL)", connection);
da.Fill(izpis_podatkov);
```

Thank you!

Comment: First off, you might try a SQL statement with valid syntax.

Comment: Sorry, that was just to clarify where I have the problem...I do have working syntax in my application obviously. I was just asking if there is a way to do what I would like...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you restore the database but leave the code as it is then there's a mismatch between code and database schema. The simplest option would be to alter the table to add the missing column after you do the restore. Something like:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD newcolumn VARCHAR(255)
```

Obviously, changing the table, column name and data type to the appropriate values for your situation.

**EDIT:**

You could do something closer to what you actually asked by creating a stored procedure that would check for the existence of the column and add it if it is not there:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `MyStoredProc` ()
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = `db_name` AND TABLE_NAME = `newtable` AND COLUMN_NAME = `newcolumn`) 
    BEGIN 
        ALTER TABLE 'newtable' ADD 'newcolumn' VARCHAR(255) NULL;
    END

    SELECT my_id AS Id, myColumn1 AS Column1, myColumn2 AS Column2, newcolumn AS NewColumn FROM newtable;
END
```

You would then need to change your C# code to call this stored procedure:

```
command = new MySqlCommand(procName, connection); 
da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command); 
command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
da.Fill(izpis_podatkov);
```

I don't know MySql that well so please check the syntax of the stored procedure first!

Comment: Yea, I figured I would have to do this...I'll check if column exists and if not add new column in restored database. Was just wondering if my idea would be possible with MySQL. :)

Comment: @user1080533 I've edited the answer to give an alternative that is closer to what you asked for. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a SQL Data Manipulation Language query, in MySQL, that mentions a nonexistent column in a table. The query planner in the MySQL server rejects it even if it shows up in a conditional context like `IFNULL()`.

You could use a `UNION ALL` operation, like so

```
         SELECT myColumn1, myColumn2, newColumn
           FROM newTable
          UNION ALL
         SELECT myColumn1, myColumn2, NULL as newColumn
           FROM oldTable
```

This will give you back the rows of the `newTable` and the rows of the `oldTable` as if they were a single table.   It basically hides your two tables behind the UNION, pretending they have the same layout, making an alias for the missing column in `oldTable`.

Then, if you restore the `oldTable` from backup, you can truncate (remove all rows from) the `newTable`, if that makes sense in your application.

You can use the query I showed in a `CREATE VIEW` statement, then your production software will see it as if it were `table`.

```
CREATE VIEW table AS
         SELECT myColumn1, myColumn2, newColumn
           FROM newTable
          UNION ALL
         SELECT myColumn1, myColumn2, NULL as newColumn
           FROM oldTable;
```